# how to pass an empty String from perl Script to java file as a command line argument

Tags: java, perl

I have a Script order.pl it has 3 variables

```
$dbcount=$ARGV[0];
if($dbcount == ""){$dbcount = 196001;}

$Num_Batches =$ARGV[1];
if($Num_Batches == ""){$Num_Batches=1;}
print "batches:$Num_Batches\t";

$TimeStamp = $ARGV[2];
if($TimeStamp == ""){$TimeStamp = "";}

$DBFetch = 'java GetWOConfHold_Auto '. $dbcount." ".$TimeStamp ;
print "DBFetch:$DBFetch\n";
print "timestamp :$TimeStamp";
system($DBFetch);
```

Here the java file is GetWOConfHold_Auto.java and i want to sent both dbcount and  empty String    to the GetWoConfHol_Auto  java file as a command line arguments  but

while running it is showing

```
perl order.pl 196000 1
batches:1       timestamp:      dbcount:196000  DBFetch:java GetWOConfHold_Auto 196000 

timestamp :args[0] 19600 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at GetWOConfHold_Auto.main(GetWOConfHold_Auto.java:18)
no of picking updates data : 0
No data.exiting
```

I tried to print the timestamp but it is showing

```
timestamp :args[0] 19600  not the empty String
```

and in java it is stopping at the main method signature

I want to sent the empty String to java file  as a command line argument. and  i check if timestamp is null just go and pick the value from the properties file

Comment: `== ""` is wrong, `==` compares numbers, use `eq` to compare strings in Perl.

Answer (score 3):

In the string variant of [system](http://p3rl.org/system), you need to quote the empty string.
Have you tried the list version of `system`?

```
my $DBFetch = system 'java', 'GetWOConfHold_Auto' ,$dbcount, $TimeStamp;
```